# Adding KeyListeners to JPanel not working

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I've just completed an online tutorial on making a networked game. 
The game it's self is just a small circle that follows the mouse when on the screen.

I've been modifying the code to use keys to move the circle instead of the mouse. However whilst I've done this before I've never used “JPanel” and I’m
struggling to get the keys to move the circle around.

The game's 'client' side only consists of two files, Client.java and DataPackage.java, the problem (to my knowledge) appears to be in Client.java.

I wont paste the whole code as it is quite big (i will if you think it is necessary), but here is the bit that makes the ball follow the mouse

```
public Client()
    {
        this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
            {
                x = e.getX();
                y = e.getY();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}

        });
}
```

now I've tried just changing

```
this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
                {
                    x = e.getX();
                    y = e.getY();
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}

            });
```

to

```
this.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { System.out.println( "tester"); }

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { System.out.println("2test2"); }

            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { System.out.println("3test3"); }
        });
```

but this didn't appear to work, then i tried changing the location of the keying code by putting it outside of the

```
public Client() { }
```

Then I thought it could be the 'implements' tags at the top of the file. so I added

```
implements KeyListener
```

to the end of

```
public class Client extends JComponent
```

but again, this did not work
then I did some more research and it seems that I need to set the panel to be focused by using

```
panel.setFocusable(true);
```

but the source of this information, failed to say where to put it and everywhere I put it throws an error

Can someone shed some light on this for me please?

Comment: To use keyListeners the components must be focusable and to be in focus. Better use keybindings! and try to post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) and post relevant code to your issue.

Comment: Thank you nachokk for your time, sorry for the late reply, i thought i best do some research into KeyBinding before replying. I am currently trying KeyBinding and i will let you know when i have implemented it :)

Comment: take a look at camickr article , is exactly what you need i think..

Comment: It's not enough to be a full answer, but perhaps you could have the desired panel implement `KeyListener` or `MouseMotionListener`, and then do something like `theJPanel.addMouseMotionListener(theComponentInstance);`.  I'm assuming that the JPanel will have focus all the time, and send the generated mouse/keyboard events to the component that you want to have handle it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look of @camickr ,a swing guru, article [Motion using the keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/). Using `KeyListeners` has 2 big issues, components must be focusable and have to be in focus.`KeyBindings` is the proper way to do in swing, bind a key to a particular action. [How to Use KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question, it took me a while to get my head around KeyBinding, but it's all working now